# How do I compare dates between two columns within a range of days and perform a task?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Every time there is an UNKNOWN in df, I would like to use the UNKNOWN delivery date and check against the oldest delivery date (grouped by car_part) in df2 to see if it matches within +- 90 days range? If the date matches, then print the date else go to the next UNKNOWN.

```
data = {'car_part': ['100009','100093','100071','100033','100033','100043'],
        'car_number': ['UNKNOWN', 'X123-00027C', 'X123-00027C', 'UNKNOWN', 'X123-00148C', 'X123-00148C'],
        'delivery': ['11/20/2004', '12/17/2009', '7/27/2010', '11/1/2004', '9/5/2004', '11/10/2004'],
        'test': ['12/17/2009', '7/27/2010', '7/10/2020', '12/22/2006', '3/26/2007', '12/1/2007']}  

data2 = {'delivery': ['11/1/2004', '12/1/2004', '1/1/2005', '7/1/2006', '8/1/2006', '9/2/2006'], 
         'car_part': ['100009','100009','100009','100033','100033','100033']}  

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
print(df2)

df['delivery'] = df['delivery'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
df.sort_values(by = ['car_part', 'delivery', 'test'], ascending=[True, True, True])

df2['delivery'] = df2['delivery'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
df2.sort_values(by = ['car_part', 'delivery'], ascending=[True, True])
```

I've tried doing this

```
df["delivery"] = pd.to_datetime(df["delivery"])
df2["delivery"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["delivery"])
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['car_number'] == "UNKNOWN":
        oldest_date = df["car_part"].map(df2.groupby("car_part")["delivery"].min())
        diff = (row['delivery']-oldest_date).days
        if diff<91:
            print(row['delivery'])
```

but getting error AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'days'

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: please see revised question for expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code with this. I don't really understand the final ouptut and what you are asking however your map is wrong. Since you want to use the same structure of code, the map line should be something like this

```
df["delivery"] = pd.to_datetime(df["delivery"])
df2["delivery"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["delivery"])
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['car_number'] == "UNKNOWN":
        oldest_date = df2[df["car_part"]==row["car_part"]].groupby("car_part")["delivery"].min().values[0]
        diff = (row['delivery']-oldest_date).days
        if diff<91:
            print(row['delivery'])
```

Comment: Thanks @minattosama This question and the other question you had answered is based on another question that I have but can't seem to get any traction. I think because it's like a wall of text, so I was trying to break it down into multiple questions. Here is the link to the original question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71699532/how-do-i-replace-texts-based-on-conditions-on-multiple-other-dataframe-in-python

Comment: is my post a response to the current question ?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

1. Use `groupby` and `min` to get the earliest delivery date for each car part.
2. Find the difference between the delivery in `df` and the earliest delivery date and save to `diff`
3. Keep the oldest date value only when the car number is UNKNOWN and the delivery is within 90 days from the oldest date.

```
oldest = df["car_part"].map(df2.groupby("car_part")["delivery"].min())

df["oldest"] = oldest.where(df["car_number"].eq("UNKNOWN")&df["delivery"].sub(oldest).abs().dt.days.le(90))

>>> df
  car_part   car_number   delivery        test     oldest
0   100009      UNKNOWN 2004-11-20  12/17/2009 2004-11-01
1   100093  X123-00027C 2009-12-17   7/27/2010        NaT
2   100071  X123-00027C 2010-07-27   7/10/2020        NaT
3   100033      UNKNOWN 2004-11-01  12/22/2006        NaT
4   100033  X123-00148C 2004-09-05   3/26/2007        NaT
5   100043  X123-00148C 2004-11-10   12/1/2007        NaT
```

Comment: I'm pretty new to python, can you elaborate on the answer for me to understand?

Comment: @shuynh84 - Added some points on what the code is doing. For details on each function, you will have to see the official documentation like for [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

Comment: This is kind of what I am looking for as far as grouping and finding the earliest date. But for some reason, I thought I would have to do some kind of loops to iterate through all the UNKNOWNS. Each time there is a match, I would like to perform a task, if it doesn't match then move onto the next UNKNOWN. Apologies, I'll revise the question so it'll be clearer.

Comment: That's why it helps to post your **expected output** instead of re-editing your question.

Comment: Sorry about that

Comment: How would I go about looping this in order to perform other tasks once there is a match? Like if the date matches, then print the date else go to the next UNKNOWN @not_speshal