# How to compare dates between two columns within a certain number of days in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

When there is an UNKNOWN, I would like to compare the dates of delivery column and test column to check if the delivery date is within 90 days of test date. If it is, print the delivery date. If it is not, move onto the next UNKNOWN until there are no more UNKNOWN.

```
data = {'car_part': ['100009','100093','100071','100033','100033','100043'],
        'car_number': ['UNKNOWN', 'X123-00027C', 'X123-00027C', 'UNKNOWN', 'X123-00148C', 'X123-00148C'],
        'delivery': ['11/20/2004', '12/17/2009', '7/27/2010', '11/1/2004', '9/5/2004', '11/10/2004'],
        'test': ['12/17/2004', '7/27/2010', '7/10/2020', '12/22/2006', '3/26/2007', '12/1/2007']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

The expected result should show only 11/20/2004 printed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df["test"] = pd.to_datetime(df["test"])
df["delivery"] = pd.to_datetime(df["delivery"])
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['car_number'] == "UNKNOWN":
        diff = (row['test']-row['delivery']).days
        if diff<91:
            print(row['delivery'])
```

it can be written much more efficient but I'm taking into account your level of python, it might be easier for your to learn it this way

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! The answer given is great because I am new to python. I'm trying to break down a bigger task that I want done into smaller component. If you can check out the other post as well...it would be really awesome! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71769930/how-do-i-compare-dates-between-two-columns-within-a-range-of-days-and-perform-a

Comment: No problem. It is good starting from 0 and slowly learning.  In your other question the problem comes from df["car_part"].map etc. If you print df["car_part"] you will get a series instead of one value. In this exemple (row['test']-row['delivery']) both are values, one date. In your case it is a columns